# Is ∞ the mathematical limit to any quantity?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

For example, assuming someone figured out how to bypass all physical limitations, they would never be able to have more than infinity for any physical quantity. Even if you multiplied infinity by any other number or added ∞ to ∞ (- and / are discounted since they decrease a number), you would still end up with infinity. Assuming that mathematics is the foundation of all things [per Roger Penrose,[1](https://hrstraub.ch/en/the-theory-of-the-three-worlds-penrose/) then the fact that you will never get a number higher than ∞ should mean that ∞ is the "limit" to all quantities of things. Even assuming you were omnipotent and could make your own universe, you would never have over ∞ J of energy and you would never have over ∞ number of universes. In addition, one can never even *get* to ∞, since for every number you get there is another one. Is my logic right?

Comment: ∞ is a symbol that is made sense of only in connection with real numbers, not "any physical quantity". For many physical quantities, like vectors, it makes no sense to talk about "more" and "less". And for integers mathematicians figured out a way to go beyond ∞ using powersets, addition and multiplication are not the only operations in mathematics, see [transfinite numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_number).

Comment: "you would never have over ∞ number of universes".  If you are using infinity to count things, there are many distinct infinities. In fact for any infinity there are larger infinities, so there are an infinite number of infinities. And for any infinite collection of infinities, there are larger infinite collections of infinities. There is in no sense a largest infinity.

Comment: With the exception of a [few](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line) [obscure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectively_extended_real_line) [contexts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere), ∞ is not a number, so it doesn't make sense to treat it like one.

Comment: Any number can be a limit and not hust the various infinities ...

Answer (score 0):

Georg Cantor's diagonal argument proofs that there are infinites bigger than others and that you can always build a infinite bigger then other using powersets.

That only think that would limit your infinite in some certain context is the maximun cardinality that is allowed to have in the respective context.